# jQuery: How to replace content with JSON response

Tags: json, jquery

I am having difficulty replacing the content of an HTML element with a JSON object property.  Here's my code:

```
url  = '/blah/blah-blah';
data = $.getJSON(url);
$(this).parent('.status').replaceWith(data.content);
```

Now, I know that the correct JSON object is being returned and that it includes a properly formatted property called 'content'.  (I am displaying it in the console).  Secondly, I know that I am selecting the correct element to replace.  (If I replace `data.content` with 'bingo!' I see the text displayed on screen.)

When I run the code above, however, I see the content of my element replaced with nothing.  What am I doing wrong?

Note that I tried replacing `data.content` with `data.responseJSON.content`, but that didn't help.

Thanks!

Comment: What about the [`$.getJSON` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) makes you think it *returns* the JSON string and/or deserialized data?

Comment: What do you get when you do console.log(data) or console.log(data.content)?

Comment: in the console are you correctly displaying the raw json response or the js object? in other words, are you sure data.content actually is not undefined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a callback,

```
  url  = '/blah/blah-blah';
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    $("some selector").parent('.status').replaceWith(data.content);
  })
```

In your example, $.getJSON doesn't return anything meaningful -- probably just 'undefined'.  Meanwhile, it makes your request.  When getJSON succeeds, the result is passed to a handling function which does things with it.  If you don't provide a callback, nothing will happen when you get a response back from the server.

*or* if you don't want to use a new selector, you can save $(this).

```
  url  = '/blah/blah-blah';
  item = $(this)
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    item.parent('.status').replaceWith(data.content);
  })
```

Comment: I see.  But if I define the function as a callback, does $(this) still refer to the element that was clicked?

Comment: Ah, no it doesn't, that's a good point.  You'll need to select it differently.  I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The AJAX call is asynchronous, so the content hasn't arrived yet when you try to use it. When you display it in the console, you can't do that fast enough to see that the response doesn't arrive immediately.

Use a callback in the `getJSON` call to handle the data when it arrives:

```
url = '/blah/blah-blah';
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  $(this).parent('.status').replaceWith(data.content);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is executing before the `.getJSON(url)` call is completing.  Try specifying a success handler like so:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    $(this).parent('.status').replaceWith(data.content);
});
```